High Cpu Temperature Values
I saw high temperature on cpu when gaming and recently cleaned up the laptop from dust and changed the thermal paste. So, here are the stressed temperature values:

I'm sure that there is no problem with thermal paste, cooler and processor isn't damaged. I'm asking this question because, I need to testify this temperature is normal or not. Some people say that it's normal for laptop processors and they run as fast as possible to achieve 100 degree then thermal throttling will block them to go up than 100 celsius. The easiest solution is undervolting but, H series of processors cannot be undervolted. So I ask again: is this normal or abnormal and are there any solutions?

if you can verify those temps with another tool like speedfan, and the system is more or less idle, then yes somthing is wrong. you may want to check the job on the thermal paste. make sure there is good solid contact between the cpu and the heatsink, and make sure you plugged all the fans back in. perhaps some of the fans need replaced. not a lot of structured guidance we can give on this one.

What pattern did you use when applying new paste? Did you clean the old paste off with isopropyl alcohol? Have you re-attached the heatsink properly?

Yo, it's stressed values and cause of these values i changed the thermal paste and nothing changed.
EDIT: I apply thermal paste(MX-4) evenly and don’t think that the problem is cooling

If you don’t think that the problem is cooling then why ask how to decrease the temperature?

"i changed the thermal paste and nothing changed." does that mean you were experiencing these temps before cleaning it and replacing the thermal paste? if that is the case than I suspect one of your fans has failed, and needs replacing. probably the fan on your heatsink.

Sometimes when concentrating on one problem we miss how something external may be contributing to the issue.  You are looking at CPU temperatures, and have double checked your thermal paste application, but is your CPU being cooled sufficiently (ie. could the fan be clogged), and is the airflow working well in  your case.
It is possible you may find you can lower overall temperature by checking that the direction of air in your fans, replacing/repairing fans that are not working optimally, and perhaps even just removing airflow obstructions (perhaps move your graphics card, cable management or even just move your pc away from an obstruction or heat source).
